# Python program using too much memory

Tags: python, optimization, memory, profiling

I got these results from Heapy, but it's unclear what exactly they mean.

```
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 262539  59 36961284  48  36961284  48 dict (no owner)
     1  65536  15 34340864  45  71302148  93 dict of myobj.Container
     2  65536  15  2097152   3  73399300  96 myobj.Container
```

myobj is a class with about 20 True/False values and 20 number values (all of which could by stored in 2 bytes).

I have an array of 256*256 of them. I really don't see why they consume 35 or 70 MB of memory. I'd like to bring it below 10 MB if possible.

Much of the data inside the object is organized into dictionaries for ease of access. The dictionaries themselves don't change and are rather pointless. Would they cause much overhead?

Would it be beneficial to pack all the data into 1 number with bitwise operators? I should be able to store the entire data of the object in 32 or 64 bytes. I was hoping the compiler would do this sort of thing automatically like other languages, but it seems to be doing the opposite.

The class inherits builtin type object for no reason other than to use decorators. Would this cause much overhead?

Also curious what "dict (no owner)" means and what it's consuming the other half of the memory.

Edit: sys.getsizeof(myobj.Container) is indeed reporting 450 bytes! This is insane. I only used dictionaries because I need to access data based on an index. As far as I'm concerned the compiler should get rid of the structures and access the values directly. Is there a better way to do that? (I don't imagine Lists are the answer)

Comment: You may want to consider posting your code (or a selection thereof) at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. There you'll get commentary on your actual code which will be better then whatever speculation you get based on just your description and heapy results.

Comment: *As far as I'm concerned the compiler should get rid of the structures and access the values directly.* Python almost does no optimizations. What you think is constant might change at runtime e.g., `len(x)` can return different results even if `x` is the same (because you can replace `len` at any time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't eliminate the overhead of structures like that. Sorry. Its dynamic nature makes 
such compiler optimizations difficult. But then I don't know any language that would eliminate the overhead introduced by keeping things in dictionaries.

dict (no owner) probably includes all the dictionaries you are creating inside your object. They are marked as no-owner because they aren't dictionaries for object instances.

What you can do:

Use `__slots__`, if you add `__slots__ = ('the','names','of','fields')` as a class attribute, python will use a more efficient implementation of the class. It will get rid of the dictionary used to hold the attributes.

If your dictionaries can be rewritten to use lists that would improve the situation. Lists are more memory efficient then dictionaries.

For the best efficiency you should rework your system to use numpy arrays. Each attribute in your class would become a 256*256 sized array. Each element will be stored very efficiently space-wise in that case.

Alternatively, you could checkout PyPy. It provides an alternate implementation of python with a JIT as well as various time/space optimizations which might help.

sys.getsizeof isn't reporting what you think its reporting. `sys.getsizeof(myobj.Container)` reports the size of the class object, not the size of actual Container objects. You want `sys.getsizeof(myobj.Container())` or similar. Even that's no accurate because it doesn't include anything besides the base object. It doesn't take into account the dictionary holding the attributes. It'll only report the size of the third row in your report.

Comment: Defined __slots__ for this class and one other and it cut memory use from 100 MB to 35 MB. I'm astonished that python couldn't do this itself and surprised that dictionaries waste so much space. Would you say this is true of dictionaries in general (and hence something I should look at for the other 30 MB unaccounted for), or just the __dict__ of objects? As I understand they are allocating dicts with vast extra space which is unneeded. Is there a way to define dictionaries of limited size? Also will look in numpy arrays if memory use is still an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @user1012037: when you use `__slots__`, you cannot add attributes on the fly to your objects; the increased flexibility that you get when not using `__slots__` is payed with an increased memory footprint.  Now, it is true that in most cases objects have a fixed list of attributes, so one might think that slots should be used by default; however, I guess that this would imply significant changes to the language itself.

Comment: Made a nasty switch to numpy arrays. Down to 5 MB from 100 MB. :)

Comment: @user1012037, dicts are optimized for speed not memory. They have a lot of empty space in them to reduce the chance of hash collisions. This is true of all dictionaries. PyPy does automatically do something like `__slots__` for you. However, applying the same optimization to CPython has a number of issues that make it more difficult.